# Strange behaviour of SELECT statement with constant in WHERE

Tags: sql-server, optimization, select, where-clause

I have very strange problem with MSSQL query, used in stored procedure but simplified here to show the core of the problem.

Query is following

```
SELECT vs.fv_numer FROM win.v_sprzedaz vs
```

View is quite complicated, but it takes about 2 seconds to run.
And now suprise:

```
DECLARE @test=1
SELECT vs.fv_numer FROM win.v_sprzedaz vs
WHERE @test =1
```

Now query execution takes...15 seconds!

Due to lack of knowledege I did not analyzed execution plan in details (in both cases it is different and quite complicated). Any ideas WHY???

Comment: Is tyhat your exact query or have you actually combined the `@test =1` predicate with another predicate with `AND` or `OR`? Also what if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess the where clause is causing the indexes used in the view to not be consulted. You need to put some [QUERY HINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)s into the view query to enforce them.

Without knowing your DB it's hard to put a finger on it. But to me it smells like the query plan is not able to optimised as well.

My preferred way of solving problems like this is to take the view query and gradually and add the @test to it and see what changes, and then investigate by gradually removing conditions until the @test make no difference. Then you see the clash. You then need to investigate how to best add optimisation as this could impact other use cases for the view.